# Chrome for Testing (aka CfT)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, cft, chrome-for-testing

By chance reading https://pptr.dev/chromium-support
I found [New Chrome brand: Chrome for Testing document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XJvxyqAQjhPfJ0rX84PjfXXb5sBx3m8DXzMxR0ipQNs/edit#heading=h.xzptrog8pyxf),
however I cannot google anything.
(Though [other search engine](https://www.qwant.com/?q=Chrome%20for%20Testing&t=web) gave me results like

- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

What is Chrome for Testing/Cft in short words?
What URL to use when pointing other developers?

Comment: IMO Summary in the linked document answers your first question well.

Answer (score 1):

**CfT** For testing is launched by Chrome. Here is a complete article that [how we can run Selenium/Automated tests on CFT and what are its feature](https://qatestauto.com/run-selenium-tests-on-chrome-for-testing-know-everything-about-this/).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for Testing author here.

I wrote a [blog post](https://thiagowfx.github.io/2024/01/google-chrome-for-testing-reliable-downloads-for-browser-automation/) in my personal blog which answers most of your questions.

The official references though are these two:

- Original Google Blog announcement post about CfT: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing
- Chrome for Testing design document (public): https://goo.gle/chrome-for-testing

For support, use the official github repository of the project: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing